Android Companion Device Manager Fails to Recognize Associated BluetoothLE Device After Reboot
I am developing an Android app that utilizes the Companion Device Manager (CDM) to connect with associated devices. My implementation uses the startObservingDevicePresence method, which functions correctly after installing the app and associating the device. However, after rebooting the phone (which could be triggered by OS updates or manual restarts), the CDM does not recognize the associated devices anymore.
This seems to work on Samsung phones after reboot, but not on different manufactures.
It works on:

Samsung S20 (Android 13)
Samsung S23 (Android 13)
Samsung S23 Ultra (Android 14)

It does not work on

Google Pixel 6a (Android 13)
Nothing Phone 2 (Android 13)
OnePlus 8 pro (Android 13)

I expect that the CompanionDeviceService would trigger the onDeviceAppeared method, when the associated device is in proximity of the phone. This works after installing the app and associating the device, but it stops working when rebooting the phone.
I've tried the following:

Manually start the CompanionService using a BroadcastReceiver listening for the BOOT_COMPLETED action.
Stop observing and start observing on all associated devices on BOOT_COMPLETED, with the use of stopObservingDevicePresence and startObservingDevicePresence in the deviceManager.
I introduced a foreground service that starts after the device reboots and then shuts down shortly afterward. This was an attempt to ensure that the app is activated post-reboot.
I also tried manually connecting to the BLE device through the phone's Bluetooth settings. Interestingly, this action triggered the companion service's onDeviceAppeared method. However, it should happen without the need of manually connecting to the device through the Bluetooth settings on the phone.

Here is the code snippets related to the implementation of CDM in the app:
AndroidManifest.xml:
...
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.companion_device_setup"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_USE_DATA_IN_BACKGROUND" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_OBSERVE_COMPANION_DEVICE_PRESENCE" />
...

        <service
            android:name="CompanionService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="connectedDevice"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_COMPANION_DEVICE_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.companiondevicemanager.action.BIND_SERVICE" />
                <action android:name="android.companion.CompanionDeviceService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
...

Code to associate device from Google's documentation:
private const val SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE = 0

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val deviceManager: CompanionDeviceManager by lazy {
        getSystemService(Context.COMPANION_DEVICE_SERVICE) as CompanionDeviceManager
    }
    val mBluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter by lazy { 
        val java = BluetoothManager::class.java
        getSystemService(java)!!.adapter }
    val executor: Executor =  Executor { it.run() }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // To skip filters based on names and supported feature flags (UUIDs),
        // omit calls to setNamePattern() and addServiceUuid()
        // respectively, as shown in the following  Bluetooth example.
        val deviceFilter: BluetoothDeviceFilter = BluetoothDeviceFilter.Builder()
            .setNamePattern(Pattern.compile("My device"))
            .addServiceUuid(ParcelUuid(UUID(0x123abcL, -1L)), null)
            .build()

        // The argument provided in setSingleDevice() determines whether a single
        // device name or a list of them appears.
        val pairingRequest: AssociationRequest = AssociationRequest.Builder()
            .addDeviceFilter(deviceFilter)
            .setSingleDevice(true)
            .build()

        // When the app tries to pair with a Bluetooth device, show the
        // corresponding dialog box to the user.
        deviceManager.associate(pairingRequest,
            executor,
            object : CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
                // Called when a device is found. Launch the IntentSender so the user
                // can select the device they want to pair with.
                override fun onAssociationPending(intentSender: IntentSender) {
                intentSender?.let {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(it, SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0)
              }
            }

             override fun onAssociationCreated(associationInfo: AssociationInfo) {
                 // AssociationInfo object is created and get association id and the 
                 // macAddress.
                 var associationId: int = associationInfo.id
                 var macAddress: MacAddress = associationInfo.deviceMacAddress
             }
             override fun onFailure(errorMessage: CharSequence?) {
                // Handle the failure.
            }
    )

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode) {
            SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE -> when(resultCode) {
                Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                    // The user chose to pair the app with a Bluetooth device.
                    val deviceToPair: BluetoothDevice? =
                        data?.getParcelableExtra(CompanionDeviceManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                    deviceToPair?.let { device ->
                        deviceManager?.startObservingDevicePresence(device.address)
                    }
                }
            }
            else -> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
}

CompanionService.kt:
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
class CompanionService : CompanionDeviceService() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Timber.d("Companion - onCreate")
    }

    override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
        Timber.d("Companion - onUnbind")
        return super.onUnbind(intent)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun onDeviceAppeared(associationInfo: AssociationInfo) {
        Timber.d("Companion - onDeviceAppeared")
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onDeviceAppeared(address: String) {
        Timber.d("Companion - onDeviceAppeared")
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun onDeviceDisappeared(associationInfo: AssociationInfo) {
        Timber.d("Companion - onDeviceDisappeared")
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onDeviceDisappeared(address: String) {
        Timber.d("Companion - onDeviceDisappeared")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Timber.d("Companion - onDestroy")
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}

The same issue seems to happen for the Google sample project on Companion Device Manager: Link here
